# JSON FOR PATH in a subselect returns only unique values

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

If I do a subselect with newid() I (as expected) get a unique token value for reach row in the results:

```
select top 3
person_id,
(
  select 
    newid() as token  
) as token
from person
```

results in

```
person_id, token

325537     6c3eba8f-a43f-4987-8571-02442e9e5979
339904     3ef9017a-90ac-42ec-a7ac-478767ae491b
470741     d4de6b1f-2a21-4bcb-8214-54eb40b2031e
```

but if I wrap this in `for json path`, it generates a single token, and reuses it:

```
select top 3
person_id,
(
  select 
    newid() as token
  for json path, without_array_wrapper  
) as token
from person
```

results

```
325537  {"token":"091C23DF-0D4D-4FBD-A6B6-4448375DAFD5"}
339904  {"token":"091C23DF-0D4D-4FBD-A6B6-4448375DAFD5"}
470741  {"token":"091C23DF-0D4D-4FBD-A6B6-4448375DAFD5"}
```

If however, there's another **unique** value in the token subselect that makes the results unique, it all works as expected

```
select top 3
person_id,
(
  select 
    newid() as token,
    person_id
  for json path, without_array_wrapper  
) as token
from person
```

results

```
325537  {"token":"75638DAE-8861-4E38-81E5-EF558A7CFA81","person_id":325537}
339904  {"token":"1E223719-B08E-4930-8015-D5127F23A80B","person_id":339904}
470741  {"token":"8FE3524A-D6DB-4FE7-B526-C43B8F654929","person_id":470741}
```

Clearly, it's related to the uniqueness of the results, but I can't figure out any way to get a unique value for each row without padding it with data I don't really need.

**Update**, as a work around, separating the newid() into a CTE accomplishes the goal, but I still don't understand what's going on with the original query.

```
with records as (
  select top 10
  person_id, newid() as token
  from person p
)

select
  person_id,
  (select token for json path, without_array_wrapper) as context
from records
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by separating creating `NEWID()`'s from converting to json:

```
with x as (
    select top 3 p.person_id, NEWID() x
    from person p
)
select x.INVENTLOCATIONID, x.x, j.j
from x
    cross apply (
        select x.x for json path, without_array_wrapper
    )j(j)
```

btw, `for xml` also produces the same UIDs for all rows